# If graphQL uses an async concept and has http capability why does it conflict with the REST API design of Node/Express with http?

Tags: express, http, graphql, express-graphql

I've set up a TypeScript/Node/Express API that includes 'http' for REST and 'express-graphql'. After coding the schema, resolvers and types for TypeScript conformity I run with nodemon ts-node and everything is fine with 'http' requests. When I send a graphQL Query via Postman as a POST it just hangs. I've never seen anything like this that does not time out and it could be running for minutes. Postman shows some unusual 'read RECONNECT' error. Why is graphQL this problematic. Why doesn't it just fit in instead of suggesting the replacement of a perfectly proven process like REST?

Comment: You're experiencing a specific issue with your GraphQL code, you're not sharing said code and you're using it as an argument asking for people to defend GraphQL vs REST? If you have a specific issue you would like to get help with, at a minimum share code, output, etc. Nobody can guess why your server is hanging.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Its more a question of what is the point of graphQL. It seems redundant and problematic. Perhaps I should simply ask why we are replacing a design that works with one that requires more moving parts has a divided community and more questions than answers.